# Do the automorphism groups of $F_2$ and $G$ act transitively on the surjections from $F_2$ to $G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite nonabelian group.

Let $F_2$ be the free group with generators $x,y$, then we know its outer automorphism group is isomorphic to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}$). Let $\text{Aut}^+(F_2)$ be the (index 2) subgroup of $\text{Aut}(F_2)$ mapping onto $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\subset\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (via some fixed isomorphism $\text{Out}(F_2)\cong\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$).

Let's say that $G$ is "nice" if there is a surjection $\rho : F_2\twoheadrightarrow G$ with the property that *every* surjection $F_2\twoheadrightarrow G$ can be written as $\alpha\circ\rho\circ\varphi$ where $\alpha\in\text{Aut}(G)$, and $\varphi\in\text{Aut}^+(F_2)$.

Say it's "almost nice" if we allow $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(F_2)$.

Is every 2-generated group "nice" or "almost nice"?

Is there some similar class of groups that people have studied? It's important for my research to have a nice characterization of these groups, however I'm not a group theorist and hopefully I won't have to start from scratch when analyzing these groups.

thanks

Comment: Thurston and Dunfield (Inventiones, 2006) looked at the case of surface groups and epimomorphisms to simple finite groups. They proved that (if genus is high w/r to the fixed G) equivalence classes of epimorphisms are determined by a single invariant, the "Euler class".

Comment: Well, $G$ has to be $2$-generated, so lots of $G$ are not "nice"

Comment: thanks, though of course the real question is whether every 2-generated group is "nice/almost nice".

Comment: Some terminology: the words you're looking for are 'Nielsen equivalence'.  A group is '(almost?) nice' in your definition if all generating pairs are Nielsen equivalent.

Comment: Here's a useful fact which will answer your question.  (I was just reminded of it in a paper of Kapovich and Weidmann).  $\mathrm{Aut}(F_2)$ preserves the conjugacy class of the subgroup generated by the commutator of the generators (since every automorphism can be realized on a punctured torus). So any two generating pairs whose commutators are not conjugate (or conjugate to each other's inverses) provide an example of non-Nielsen-equivalent generating pairs.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer to [your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215193/transitive-actions-of-autf-2-on-surjections-from-f-2-twoheadrightarrow-g/242500#242500), I give references supporting the fact that almost all finite non-abelian simple groups aren't "almost nice".

So I would rather ask: Is there an handy characterization of "(almost) nice" groups?

Since counting the $T_2$-systems of finite two-generated nilpotent groups of class $2$ is, I believe, still an open problem [Open Problem 2.3.5, 2] and knowing M. J. Dunwoody's result which states that arbitrarily large numbers of $T_2$-systems can be achieved in this class [1], I am tempted to say that the task of characterizing "(almost) nice" groups is not obvious.

In this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08896) it is shown for instance that split metacyclic groups (e.g., dihedral groups) and wreath products of two finite cyclic groups are "almost nice" (i.e, have only one $T_2$-system). The most general result states, when specialized to finite groups, that a two-generated finite split abelian-by-cyclic group is "almost nice", see assertion $(i)$ of Theorem $D$. The proof is elementary in this case. Since for such groups there is a generating pair $(a, b)$ such that $(a, b) \mapsto (a, b^{-1})$ induces an automorphism, these groups are actually "nice" groups.

M. J. Dunwoody's construction [1] is the quotient of a split abelian-by-cyclic group by some central subgroup. Hence the class of "almost nice" groups is not stable under quotient and the number of $T_2$-systems can dramatically increase under this operation.

---

[1] "On $T$-systems of groups", M. J. Dunwoody, 1962.
[2] "What do we know about the product replacement algorithm?", I. Pak, 2000.